# how to assign a list to another list?

Tags: java, list, collections, arraylist

i have one problem with handling list,i have three class named as UserInf,userData,userProcess,i created one  generic list using  UserInf class, and i need to set that list to another list which is in class userprocess,this my sample code*

```
public class UserInf 
{
    private List<Data> pData;

    private String userId;

public void setData(List<Data> pData)
    {
        this.pData=pData;// Need to assign the fpData
    }
    public List<Data> getData()
    {
        return this.pData;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId)
    {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserId()
    {
        return userId;
    }
```

in my other  class userdata i cretaed list using userInf,add adding the value like this

```
List<UserInf> userInformation=new ArrayList<UserInf>();
UserInf userInfo=new UserInf();
userInfo.setUserId(userid);
  userInfo.setData(pdata);
userInformation.add(userInfo);//up to this working fine


}
```

in my other class userprocees, i want to assign the userInformation list to another list i created object for userInf class ang get the property and assign to my new list

```
List<UserInf> userProcessList=new ArrayList<UserInf>();
UserInf userProcess=new UserInf();
userProcess.getData();
userProcess.getUserId();
userProcessList.add(userProcess);//problem is here
```

but this is not working how to assign list to another list like this in java

Comment: You are trying to getData() from userProcess. This should be set i think.If you write error message here, we can answer properly.

Comment: Not make sense, `UserInf userProcess = new UserInf();` after you create the object why you do `userProcess.getData();` and `userProcess.getUserId();`? Is it the `pData` and `userId` still `null`?

Comment: can you plz state the exact error you are facing with complete code listing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this:

```
List<Int32> copy = new List<Int32>(original); 

List<Int32> copy = original.ToList();
```

Comment: can "List" be even constructed? i don't see any "ToList" method

Answer (score 2):

```
List<UserInf> userInformation=new ArrayList<UserInf>();
UserInf userInfo=new UserInf();
userInfo.setUserId(userid);
userInfo.setData(pdata);
userInformation.add(userInfo);//up to this working fine
```

Now create new List by passing previous list as parameter.

```
List<String> userProcessList=new ArrayList<String>(userInformation);
```